# Disabling single quotes in shell script

Tags: sh

I want the following command to execute 100 times in for loop

```
cleos push action bescouted registeracc '[$RANDOM]' -p bescouted
cleos push action bescouted vote '[0,$i]' -p bescouted
```

With variables "$RANDOM" and "$i" showing their real values, but now commands in single quotes are counted as strings. How can I make commands in single quotes execute as written with showed variables instead as strings?

My current script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cleos push action bescouted posting '[0,"a"]' -p bescouted

for i in {1..100}
do
  cleos push action bescouted registeracc '[$RANDOM]' -p bescouted
  cleos push action bescouted vote '[0,$i]' -p bescouted
done
```

current output:

```
cleos push action bescouted registeracc [$RANDOM] -p bescouted
cleos push action bescouted vote [0,$i] -p bescouted
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is: cleos push action bescouted registeracc '[RANDOM VARIABLE]' -p bescouted
cleos push action bescouted vote '[0,loop number]' -p bescouted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes.

```
cleos push action bescouted registeracc "[$RANDOM]" -p bescouted
cleos push action bescouted vote "[0,$i]" -p bescouted
```